# jQuery not working in Brackets

Tags: jquery, html, adobe-brackets

I am new to IDE's in general so I started with Brackets and I'm not sure what's wrong. I have an HTML, CSS, and Javascript file, and at the least the HTML and CSS files are working. The JQuery isn't, and I don't know if it's because the HTML can't find the Javascript file or if my code is just wrong and not working.
The names of the files are: html.htm, worksheet.css, and script.js. My HTML code looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('div').click(function () {
    $(this).effect('explode');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: purple;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='worksheet.css'/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help and time, I really appreciate it!

Comment: In general jquery should be included *before* the jquery-ui library. -- and I personally, have no clue what `'use strict;'` is supposed to do since it's just a random string.

Comment: @Scott is helpful to avoid some errors by catching them in development ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Comment: and speaking of errors... look in your browser console. Will see error due to incorrect script order

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl helpful and clearly new to me :)

Comment: Okay so I switched the JQuery and JQuery-UI library, and @charlietfl I checked my browser console; it said "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined", and "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". Any idea what the problem is with that?

Comment: your script needs to be after the libraries also... it is dependent on them. As for the 404, path is wrong